# jquery mobile: Linking within a multi-page document

Tags: jquery-mobile

In jquery mobile documentation http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

it is said that I need to have a div with certain ID to navigate it.

I have a jquery moblie page div:

```
<div id="payments" data-role="page" data-url="payments">
```

On the other page I have a like

```
<a href="#payments" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Open dialog</a>
```

But when I click it nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have an error somewhere else in your code, do you get any errors in your console after clicking the button? It would be helpful for you to setup a JSFiddle to share more of your code.

Here is a demo of your code working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/zteV3/

Comment: Ah yes, I dont know what the mistake was, but I works now. thanks.